# QML: Column not working with Custom Types

Tags: qt, qml

So I have some Custom Types aligned in a `Column`. However when I run the program they get displayed on the same row. What am I missing here?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column{

        OSDisplay{
            osName: "Kde Neon User Edition"
        }
        KernelDisplay{
            kernelName: "Kernel: 5.3.0-51-generic"
        }
        //....
    }
}
```

OSDisplay.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    property string osName: ""

    Text{
        anchors.fill: parent

        text: "OS: " + parent.osName
    }
}
```

KernelDisplay.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    property string kernelName: ""

    Text{
        anchors.fill: parent

        text: "Kernel: " + parent.kernelName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your custom types rectangle needs width and height.

e.g.KernelDisplay.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
  width: 100  // or your text.width
  height: 50 // or your text.height
  property string kernelName: ""

  Text{
    anchors.fill: parent

    text: "Kernel: " + parent.kernelName
  }
}
```